# Get values from json using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am making a login app in ionic using PHP, I have a login function which works well but I need to be able to store certain values to local storage for later use.

Here is a sample from my code:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    Login.login($scope.login).then(function (data) {
        if (Object.keys(data.data).length === 1) {
            var datao = angular.toJson(data);
            $scope.profile = datao;
            $scope.email = $scope.profile.email;
            $scope.username = $scope.profile.username;
            console.log(data);
            console.log($scope.profile);
              // $state.go('dashboard');
        }
        ....
    });
    ....
});
```

`$scope.profile` displays the following:

```
[Log]
     {
        "data": [{
            "id": "5",
            "username": "ozombo",
            "reputation": "ceo",
            "activate": "8425",
            "followercount": "3",
            "praycount": "0",
            "donetour": "0",
            "fb_id": "0",
            "fullname": "Adebambo Oyelaja",
            "church": "RCCG ",
            "photo": "1417451697.jpg",
            "twtr_id": "0",
            "screen_name": "",
            "email": "oyexs911@yahoo.com",
            "bio": "Geek, Father, Husband",
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "state": "Lagos",
            "followscount": "0",
            "account": "",
            "password": "5cf1bc1b9a2ada1ae9e29079aae1aefa",
            "signup_date": "1413305984",
            "signupdevice": "web",
            "keycode": "5fc868f0767b0c164341a9e8e35edbe4",
            "last_login": "1436519269",
            "city": "Palmgroove",
            "campaign": "",
            "bday": "29-09-1988",
            "gender": "Male",
            "approved": "0",
            "donewelcome": "0",
            "phonenumber": "07017993683",
            "secure": "private",
            "churchid": "1",
            "views": "68",
            "marital": "Married"
        }],
        "status": 200,
        "config": {
            "method": "GET",
            "transformRequest": [null],
            "transformResponse": [null],
            "url": "http://localhost:8888/opb/api/login.php?user=oyexs911@yahoo.com&pass=oyelaja",
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /"
            }
        },
        "statusText": "OK"
    }
```

How will I get the user email for example

Answer (score 1):

You can get the email by accesing to data.email like `var email = $scope.profile.data.email`

You forgot that you have **data** before you can get the email.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "username": "ozombo",
    "email": "oyexs911@yahoo.com",
    ...
  }]
}
```

Comment: var email = $scope.profile.data.email isn't working... Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.profile.data.email')

Comment: if $scope.profile logs what you shows in the post you can acces like i said

Comment: Yes my logs show what i posted but when i do this:
 $scope.profile = datao;
console.log($scope.profile.data.email); 
i get Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.profile.data.email')

Comment: Could you please try `$scope.profile.data[0]` ? From what I see, your data object is actually a table, containing objects.

Comment: @trichetriche var email = $scope.profile.data[0]; gives undefined is not an object fernando data displays {data: Array, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: or `console.log(datao.data[0])`, which sould display your first user Ozombo.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the user email by iterating over the `data` array:

```
$scope.profile.data.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d.email);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: after doing this, i get Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.profile.data.forEach')

Comment: There isn't any way that this can be the case if what you provided in the question is accurate. Can you do `console.log($scope.profile.data);` and show your output?

Comment: undefined is what i get

Comment: This should be showing your first user. What does `console.log($scope.profile);` give you?

Comment: [Log] {"data":[{"id":"5","username":"ozombo","reputation":"ceo","activate":"8425","followercount":"3","praycount":"0","donetour":"0","fb_id":"0","fullname":"Adebambo Oyelaja","church":"RCCG ","photo":"1417451697.jpg","twtr_id":"0","screen_name":"","email":"oyexs911@yahoo.com","bio":"Geek, Father, Husband","country":"Nigeria","state":"Lagos","followscount":"0","account":"","password":"5cf1bc1b9a2ada1ae9e29079aae1aefa","signup_date":"1413305984","signupdevice":"web","keycode":"5fc868f0767b0c164341a9e8e35edbe4","last_login":"1436519269", please refer to my question for full LOG